# In Firefox, how do I see HTTP request headers? (where in web console?)

Tags: firefox, http-headers

(Edited, I had 'in 2016' but it's not 2016 yet. I meant 'currently')

Things that haven't worked for me so far:

Looking at web console functionality in Firefox (I may be blind)

Looking at web console documentation at [mozilla.org - web console doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console) (the video won't play; I may be missing it.  People say it's in the web console but I don't see any headers in the web console.  I expect to see meta tags, and redirects in particular are driving me nuts at the moment.)

Tried a couple expired addons in Firefox (there's a fix claimed but I doubt it works yet - [search for addons at mozilla.org](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=http%20headers)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Open the Developer Tools. Select the Network tab. Click on the item you wish to examine the headers for.

You won't see any meta tags though since they are not HTTP headers but are part of the HTML document that could be delivered in the response body.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: And you can see the meta tags in the Page Info window (right-click on the page, View Page Info)