# why does 'location' header field redirects immediately and other header fields don't when used with header() function in php

Tags: php, html, apache, http

According to the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/)

> [header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) — Send a raw HTTP header

Now,

when I use following code :

```
header('location:form.html');
```

then, the *header* function immediately redirects the browser to *form.html* OR simply an HTTP response header is sent immediately after the execution of above line.

but when I use same *header* function to add some other header fields to the response header, for example:

```
header("X-Sample-Test: foo");
header('Content-type: text/plain');
```

then why doesn't it send an HTTP response header immediately?

First of all, correct me if I am wrong and secondly please do share more information on HTTP headers.

Comment: Manual also says that using "Location" is a "special case" of the `header()` function. So yes, it works differently.

Answer (score 1):

As was alluded to in a comment, the [PHP.net documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) states that:

> *The second special case is the "Location:" header. Not only does it send this header back to the browser, but it also returns a REDIRECT (302) status code to the browser unless the 201 or a 3xx status code has already been set.*<sup>[1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)</sup>.

Thus that header is a **special case**.

> but when I use same header function to add some other header fields to the response header

```
header("X-Sample-Test: foo");
header('Content-type: text/plain');
```

> then why don't it sends a HTTP response header immediately.

It still sends those headers (you should be able to see them in a browser console - e.g. In a *networking* tab) but the browser doesn't send the user to a different URL like it does for a redirect header.

Take a look at the image below, where I inspected the response headers in the network tab after loading a PHP page with those headers. I highlighted those headers coming through. For more information about viewing headers see these answers for [Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4423097/1575353) or [Mozilla Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33974626/1575353).

[image: inspecting headers]

You may find it interesting to read some of the (positive-voted) user contributed notes on [that documentation page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php</sub>