# HTML Form Post Method to PHP: $_POST Empty

Tags: php, html, post

I searched several other similar questions, but none of them helped me out.

I'm working on a form that will post to a db using PHP, but the post data is not being sent. $_POST is an empty array, and file_get_contents('php://input') returns an empty string.

Here is an MWE.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>   
<div class="content">
    <form action="formprocessor.php" method="post">
        <label>Name: </label>
        <input name="name" type="text" />

        <label>Email: </label>
        <input name="email" type="text" />

        <input name="mySubmit" type="submit" value="Submit!" />
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**formprocessor.php:**

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);

var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input')); //returns string(0) ""
//or
var_dump($_POST); //returns array(0) {}

echo $_POST;
?>
```

The html and php are in separate files in the same directory.  After submitting this form, I get this in the browser:

```
string(0) "" array(0) { } Array
```

Running PHP 5.3.28 on Windows Server 2008

I am confident there is nothing wrong with the code, but probably something to do with the server or php configuration.  Any direction there would be helpful.

I have checked the configuration file.  The only setting I was able to identify that is relevant is post_max_size, which has the value 8M.

Here's what the Network tab shows on Chrome's developer tools after submitting the form:
[image]

Comment: Not your issue, but do not `echo var_dump()`.  Rather, `var_dump()` alone produces output always on its own and never returns a string to `echo`.

Comment: The code as it is posted is all correct. Do you have other PHP forms functioning correctly on this server already? I'm trying to think of a configuration in either PHP or Win Server (where I'm very rusty) that would hinder POST.

Comment: noted and corrected.  Thank you.

Comment: This is the first form that uses PHP on this server.

Comment: error reporting shows you what? https://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: you're also not doing anything with the POST arrays; echo them out and see what happens along with what I posted above. Is this one or two separate files? @CWill85 this comment was edited.

Comment: I just tested your code on a server, and it works fine , are you sure you are sending it to the correct php file?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner - Even with error_reporting(E_ALL); I get no errors.

Comment: `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` use that to catch "and" display.

Comment: Also tested the code exactly as above, and the form posts correctly to formprocessor.php with $_POST populated.

Comment: Are the HTML and PHP files on the same folder? If not then you need to either do that or fix the action of the form to the right URL.

Comment: @Innervisions, yes I am sure because it does echo back the empty $_POST and file_get_contents('php://input')

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner string(0) "" array(0) { } Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SODLR\formprocessor.php on line 11 Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SODLR\formprocessor.php on line 12

Comment: Is it possible that your apache doesn't allow posts for some reason?

Comment: @CWill85 this tells me that both your html and php are of the same file, correct?

Comment: @RBCunhaDesign yes, they are in the same folder.  I suspect this is a configuration issue and not anything to do with my code.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner No, they are separate.  HTML is TestForm.html.  PHP is formprocessor.php.

Comment: @CWill85 yeah I can see that now that you sent the error report.

Comment: am also betting that you have the php above your html/form, since lines 11 and 12 or something you're not showing us.

Comment: consult the duplicate.

Comment: @Innervisions Not sure, I'm a bit of a newb with PHP.  I checked the configuration file for PHP and the only relevant setting seems to be the max post size, which is set to 8m

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner No, they are in separate files.  I posted the entirety of both files.  There is no PHP in the HTML file.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner - this is not a duplicate.  $name and $email are undefined because the $_POST array is empty.  If I take those 2 lines of code out, the error is gone and I'm still sitting here with an empty $_POST array.

Comment: Try `var_dump($_REQUEST);`

Comment: Check your request with the web developer tool in your browser to check whether anyting gets actualy posted

Comment: @Grant I added var_dump($_REQUEST); to the php file and the browser shows "array(0) { }"

Comment: @DarkBee - does my response to Grant address the same thing you were asking for?  Thanks.

Comment: If you use chrome watch [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423061/view-http-headers-in-google-chrome), for firefox [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33974595/in-firefox-how-do-i-see-http-request-headers-where-in-web-console)

Comment: @DarkBee - I added a screenshot showing the requests on the Network tab in Chrome.  Does that tell you anything helpful?  Thanks.

Comment: Could you post your `web.config`? It's strange your `POST` get redirected from `phpcontroller.php` to `phpcontroller`

Comment: @DarkBee I have a URL rewrite to mask .html and .php file extensions.  Could that be causing problems?  I'm going to move the form out of the root directory (where the rewrite rule doesn't apply) and try it there.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to DarkBee for pointing me in the right direction, but I figured out the problem.  I have URL rewrite rules in place to mask .html and .php extensions.  This was causing the post action to redirect from "formprocessor.php" to "formprocessor", and the post data seems to be lost at that point.

I put the following in a web.config in the subdirectory to disable the rules and now it works as expected.

```
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <remove name="Redirect .php extension" />
    <remove name="hide .php extension" />
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

In hindsight, this should have been really obvious.  If anyone knows a cleaner way to avoid this conflict all together other than to disable the rewrite rules, that would be helpful.  Hope this helps some other people out.