# How to serve static assets with an efficient cache policy on Nginx?

Tags: css, image, performance, nginx, caching

## On mobile

I'm trying to improve the page load of my site

[image]

I added

```
# Media: images, icons, video, audio, HTC
location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|mp3|ogg|ogv|webm|htc|woff2|woff)$ {
    expires 1M;
    access_log off;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
}

# CSS and Javascript
location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
    expires 1y;
    access_log off;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
}
```

For some reasons, I feel like the changes that I just added to my Nginx is not taking any effect.

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bunlongheng.com%2F

## How should I debug this further ?

Answer (score 14):

You're missing the `max-age` directive, from http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html

I don't think you really want CSS and JS files to expire so far out, but I could be wrong.

Also, no logging on images and all these file types? What if you're getting hotlinked or serving CSS/JS files that can't be found.

I would rethink your cache control a bit more.

```
# Media: images, icons, video, audio, HTC
location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|mp3|ogg|ogv|webm|htc|woff2|woff)$ {
    expires 1M;
    access_log off;
    # max-age must be in seconds
    add_header Cache-Control "max-age=2629746, public";
}

# CSS and Javascript
location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
    expires 1y;
    access_log off;
    add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31556952, public";
}
```

Comment: I think this is not what is intended. [Per the docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#expires) the nginx directive `expires` will set both the `Expires` HTTP-Header to an appropriate date **and** the `max-age` in the Cache-Control header to the appropriate seconds. Responses from the above config will contain two `max-age` fields. (verified with nginx 1.18).

Comment: Well, that's easily verifiable using `curl -I https://example.com/stylesheet.css` (obviously, replacing the domain/URL with an actual file path).

Answer (score 0):

Two methods to debug [http caching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching) which I use are:

- Go to [REDbot.org](https://redbot.org/). You can enter a url and it will show you the relevant HTTP response headers together with notes on what might be wrongly configured.
- Check the **Response headers** yourself in the browser ([chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423061/how-can-i-view-http-headers-in-google-chrome), [firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33974595/in-firefox-how-do-i-see-http-request-headers-where-in-web-console)) to verfiy that your nginx config is applied.

  When e.g. `expires 1h` is set in your nginx config you should see two response headers:

  ```
  Expires: <A date one hour in the future>
  Cache-Control: max-age=3600
  ```